# Drag and Drop STL using Script?

Tags: python

Is it possible to have a panel with stl files (or icons representing them) that can be dragged and dropped into the Viewport? I've read through a number of forum posts claiming that it was in the works at some point, but I can seem to find anything conclusive.
Is there an add-on that allows that functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Drag and drop is quite limited in Blender. If you'd like to make that work properly you'd have to add that functionality in C.

Comment: Does it exist at all? If so, where is that in the documentation?

Comment: Not really. The answer says it's supposedly being worked on in 2.8. But the question is three years old, so I would be curious to see if it ever did get implemented. But based on the lack of available evidence, I'm guessing it's not

Comment: Nothing really changed since then...

Comment: Too bad, that's what I figured

Comment: You can always look into the source code for evidence. Would take some time though :) AFAIK you can drag images and blends into the viewport at the moment.

Comment: The VSE has drag and drop for adding movie clips and image strips. The Info Panel says it's calling the usual operators, so it seems like it's Python-level and you *should* be able to make it work with other panels too.